# Advice on how to create a common base class (or functionality) between a page and master?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a custom base class that my .aspx pages inherit from.

Since Master page's inherit from MasterPage and not Page, how can I create common functionality that are available in both my Pages and Master pages?

```
public class SitePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  public SitePage()
  {

  }

  public bool IsLoggedIn
  {
         //
  }

  public string HtmlTitle
  {
           //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to put all the functionality in the Master page and always call them by going through the Master page.  You can strongly type the `Master` property in `SitePage`:

```
public class SitePage : Page
{
    public new MyMaster Master { get { return base.Master as MyMaster; } }
}
```

Then access the values through the Master:

```
this.Master.IsLoggedIn
```

Answer (score 0):

**Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyProject.master.cs"
    Inherits="MyProject.MasterPages.MyProject" %>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">   
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Base page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MyProject.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BasePage.aspx.cs"
        Inherits="MyProject.BasePage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
    runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Content Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="MyProject - Home" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MyProject.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFileBaseClass="MyProject.BasePage" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
            Inherits="MyProject.Default"
                Meta_Description="Code Snippet: Master Page and Base Page"
                    Meta_Keywords="master, base, content" Theme="Style" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
   runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```